# angularjs toaster failing to change from sticky to dismiss dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am using  ([Angularjs toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster)) and my requirement is initially I need to make toasters sticky and after some particular button click, all the toasters should be dismissed as per the given interval. So initially I have given time-out to 0 and then in `pop2()` function I am setting the timeout to 2000. I can clearly see the time out in the toasterOptions object is changing to 2000 but all the toaster still remains sticky.

```
$scope.toasterOptions  = {'time-out': 0, 'close-button':true, 'animation-class': 'toast-top-center'};

$scope.pop1 = function(){
 toaster.success({title: "title1", body:"text1"});
};

$scope.pop2 = function(){
 toaster.success({title: "title2", body:"text2"});
 $scope.toasterOptions["time-out"] = 2000;
};
```

Please see the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aXK53I?p=preview)

Comment: Have you tried changing the `toastrOptions` before invoking the `toaster` itself? Meaning, inside `$scope.pop2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a time out function to call your clear function so that it will clear all at the given time span and don't forgot to add $timeout in controller

```
 $scope.pop2 = function(){
         toaster.success({title: "title2", body:"text2"});
        $timeout(function() {            
         $scope.clear();
    }, 2000);
    };
```

[**updated**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UvXs5g?p=preview)